# Problem while installing laravel on windows 10

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I try to install Laravel it gives me an error while displaying

> Could not find package Laravel/installer.

It was however found via repository search, which indicates a consistency issue with the repository.

I have already installed composer successfully

Comment: Have you tried using `composer create-project` instead of the laravel installer? `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`

Comment: How do you try to install Laravel? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: it now says *could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.